# Open Atrium: How to change Task assignment from users to groups?

Tags: nodes, views, distributions

I'm trying to change the Task content-type to be able to assign tasks to groups, and only show those tasks in Task List that are assigned to your group you are added. I've tried by adding a new field with Entity Reference to groups, to select multiple and this part is okay and working fine.

I'm blocked when I'm trying to set the filters in the Views to get the current user's group and show the task if it's assigned to that group.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the Task content-type, add a new Entity Reference field for oa_group_ref. 
Edit the Task List view and set a contextual filter on the added field, and provide the default value for the filter with the OG groups of the current user, and allow multiple values in More options.
In query settings set the Distinct to make it work with multiple assignment.